# Getting 500 error using vmware and bitbucket repo

Tags: laravel

I went from using homestead to using vmware with ubuntu installed and now when I grab my site from my bitbucket repo it doesn't want to work. I get a 500 error, but if I install a brand new laravel app it works fine. I'm not sure how to fix this or what to add here to help

Comment: I would recommend checking the error logs first when the page was loaded, make sure that there is no permissions errors etc...

Comment: That is what I did, but there was no logs in storage/logs

Comment: this is just gonna go off of a possibility, but try setting the folder permissions with a chmod and chroot for storage and see if any logs get generated

Comment: still no logs in my folder

Comment: All alright, what are you using to run it, apache, Nginx or just an artisan serve call? that way I can try and determine more about the issue

Comment: I'm using vmware workstation 16 with ubuntu installed and i'm using cpriego/valet-linux

Comment: 1) Check the nginx configuration for the site; look in /etc/nginx/sites-available and /etc/nginx/sites-enabled for the right configurations and restart nginx.  2) check the permissions for the laravel storage folder.